# Itemgetter Except Columns

Tags: python

Is there a way to get the complement of a set of columns using `itemgetter`?

For example, you can get the first, third, and fifth elements of a list using

```
from operator import itemgetter
f = itemgetter(0, 2, 4)
f(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']) ## == ('a', 'c', 'e')
```

Is there a (simple and performant) way to get all of the elements **except for** the first, third and fifth?

Comment: For an arbitrary length input? No.

Comment: Your input list doesn't have a 5th element.. in Python indexing begins at 0.

Comment: @jpp I think the common (but confusing) parlance is to call the element of the list indexed by 0 the "first" element of the list, and not, for example, the "zeroth" element.

Comment: @MichaelK, But your `itemgetter`'s first argument is `0`... which should (with your logic) raise an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to spell *everything but these indices* in Python.

You'd have to lock down the length of all inputs and hardcode the *included* indices, so `itemgetter(*(i for i in range(fixed_list_length) if i not in {0, 2, 4}))`, but then you'd be locked down to processing only objects of a specific length.

If your inputs are of *variable* length, then one distant option is to use slices to get everything after the 4th element:

```
itemgetter(1, 3, slice(5, None))
```

but then you'd get a separate list for the slice component:

```
>>> itemgetter(1, 3, slice(5, None))(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])
('b', 'd', ['f', 'g'])
```

and an error if the input sequence is not at least 4 elements long:

```
>>> itemgetter(1, 3, slice(5, None))(['a', 'b', 'c'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Rather than use `itemgetter()`, just use a set and a lambda that uses a list comprehension:

```
def excludedgetter(*indices):
    excluded = set(indices)
    return lambda seq: [v for i, v in enumerate(seq) if i not in excluded]
```

That callable can be used for inputs of any length:

```
>>> from random import randrange
>>> pile = [
...     [randrange(10) for _ in range(randrange(8))]
...     for _ in range(10)
... ]
>>> min(len(l) for l in pile), max(len(l) for l in pile)
(0, 6)
>>> sorted(pile, key=excludedgetter(0, 2, 4))
[[], [1], [9, 1, 8, 2, 4, 0], [0, 3], [7, 3, 4, 9, 7, 7], [8, 4, 4], [6, 4, 7, 9, 9], [0, 5, 3, 7, 2], [4, 6, 6, 0], [8, 8, 1]]
```

Those random-length lists are no problem.

Comment: Thanks. I figured there wasn't a (highly efficient) solution like `itemgetter` is, but this is excellent proof.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're asking about `itemgetter()` specifically: you could use a `set` to get the difference:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter

>>> obj = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> c = {1, 3, 5}  # Get everything but these
>>> get = set(range(len(obj))).difference(c)
>>> f = itemgetter(*get)
>>> f(obj)
('a', 'c', 'e')
```

where `set(range(len(obj)))` is all the indices, i.e. `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}`.

---

Disclaimer: this will not guarantee sortedness given that sets are unordered.  While it is a bit less efficient, you could be safer with:

```
f = itemgetter(*sorted(get))
```

---

Granted, this requires you to know the length of the list in advance, prior to the call to `itemgetter()`, and requires a call to that function for indexing each list.

Comment: Then why create an `itemgetter()` object **at all**? You have to create a new object each time for each list passed in.

Comment: `itemgetter()` is usually used in sorting or mapping or other setting where it is asked to process a series of objects. Unless all those objects are the same length, creating an itemgetter with all indices except the excluded ones is not practical or a good idea.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: "Unless all those objects are the same length" - they probably are, in most `itemgetter` use cases.

Comment: @user2357112: that's a very sweeping statement, though. I don't know if they are, I don't usually have a usecase for `itemgetter()` with lists beyond getting one or two elements from the 0-3 range.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a quasi-vectorised operation. This isn't possible with regular Python, or even with 3rd party NumPy where the result is an array. But the latter does offer syntactic benefits:

```
import numpy as np

A = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

exc = [0, 2, 4]

res1 = [val for idx, val in enumerate(A) if idx not in exc]
res2 = np.delete(A, exc).tolist()

assert res1 == res2
```

If you use the list comprehension, you *should* covert `exc` to `set` first to enable O(1) lookup.

Comment: These are both nice and clean, though I assume performance is not quite on the level of itemgetter.

Comment: @MichaelK, Yep, these are O(*n*) solutions. They will be slower.